# Observing varying model performance in different machines while training an activity recognition model

Tags: keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, activity-recognition, mobilenet

I am finding that my model has different performance (train and validation accuracy) on two separate machines (Laptop and PC). The code and data used are the same.

So:

- Train and Validate on Laptop (val accuracy ~91%)
- Moved the same jupyter notebook and data to PC via (manually via Box, will move to a version controlled repo shortly)
- Trained and validated on PC (val accuracy ~33%) - its a three-class classifier so its basically not learning anything
- Observing hugely varying train and validation accuracies

There are differences in versions of the libraries I am using.

Laptop (Windows 10 pro for workstations):
Tensorflow (CPU only) (2.4.1)
Keras - 2.4.1

PC (Windows 10 education):
Tensorflow (GPU enabled)- 2.1.0
Keras - 2.1.0

More on the model architecture - Activity classification based on video classification. Time distributed CNN (trained mobilenet with last 9 layers untrained) along with a GRU

Any suggestions (I am in the middle of trying to move a trained model from my laptop that has good performance to the PC and test it on the train set again to see what performance I get. If it is good I can be sure that the data in the new PC is not somehow corrupted)

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, in order to obtain the same results you should use the same `tf`  and `keras` library versions in both machines; it would be impossible to track the changes otherwise. Secondly, the GPU computation generally uses different data sizes and it impacts accuracy; you can either use CPU or GPU in both, but shouldn't change. Finally, you should set a seed when running your code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import random, os
import numpy as np

def set_seed(s):
   os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(SEED)
   os.environ['TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISTIC'] = '1'  # new flag present in tf 2.0+
   random.seed(SEED)
   np.random.seed(SEED)
   tf.random.set_seed(0)
```